# Using reshape with uneven

Tags: matlab

I'm using reshape to to window some data I have in Matlab.

```
   x = reshape(x, fs*W, []);
```

However the data I have is uneven:

```
   Eg.   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
         8 9 1 2 3 4 5
         6 7 8
```

I'm getting an error saying rehape will not work with uneven dimensions:

```
          not divisible into total number of elements, xxxx
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What else have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fill in the remaining elements with zero, `NaN` etc, and then use reshape:

```
x = rand(13,1);
num_el = numel(x);
n = 3     % Number of rows
x(numel(x) + (n - mod(numel(x), n))) = 0;

x = reshape(x, n, [])
x =

   0.15991   0.99828   0.98674   0.06898   0.78390
   0.87197   0.63062   0.16429   0.06593   0.00000
   0.73633   0.41108   0.70827   0.55363   0.00000
```

This line: `x(numel(x) + (n - mod(numel(x), n))) = 0;` assign the value `0` to the first value that is divisible by `n`. If you want `NaN`, you can do:

```
x(numel(x)+1:numel(x)+(n-mod(numel(x),3))) = NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create such a thing using reshape, this is no matrix.

To print out the data you may use:

```
fprintf('%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d\n',x);fprintf('\n')
```